# Power LED flashing orange from time to time (Asus ROG GL752vw)

Tags: power-management, laptop, asus, mate, ubuntu-mate

For those who have Asus ROG/non ROG laptops running dual boot (Windows 10 or lower), was there any fix for the randomly blinking power LED light (flashing orange)? Shutting down the system works as a remediation but the issue happens from time to time. Would be nice if there's a fix in Ubuntu's power management.

Currently running Ubuntu Mate 1.16.2, Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, Kernel 4.13.0-39

Comment: On some laptops blinking power LED may mean that system is in suspend. You can consult the manual of your laptop.

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not suspended. Doesn't happen on Windows 10 only when logging into Ubuntu.